# WinQual has moved to sysdev.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I have several programs registered with WinQual and have been successfully tracking crash reports sent via WER.  after Microsoft's update to WinQual I cannot find any of my programs on the new site.

- if I select Bug management. it says access denied your company does not have permissions.
- If I select Administrator. I am listed as the admin and my company is listed.
- if I select Reports.  none of my programs or events are listed
- if I select Reports -> Software responses. I see one response registered for a specific crash.

So what is my question? I can't find **anywhere** on the new site where I can send an e-mail to support.  Maybe someone else has had the same experience after Microsoft's "update" to WinQual and knows how to recover or view registered programs?

very frustrating not to be able to contact Microsoft.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like there's a new tool for managing products for Windows Error Reporting called Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange - this also appears to replace the Product Feedback Mapping Tool. Once you're logged into the new Dev Center you can find it here:

https://sysdev.microsoft.com/en-US/desktop/member/Telemetry/download/MetadataExchange.msi

You'll also need the Windows Live Sign In Assistant:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26686

You can then use the Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange tool to view and update your product details. It looks like it has a PowerShell interface available too.

Comment: I've also put more information up about MEME (great name) on my blog: http://www.gazoakley.com/content/getting-started-microsoft-ecosystem-metadata-exchange

Comment: well, the good news is after a couple e-mails to Microsoft, or just waiting long enough, crash reports are appearing again. I honestly can't tell if I lost historical crash reports but at least I'm collecting reports going forward.  the bad news is because I'm still running XP I can't use the MEME application and the previous Microsoft product mapping application doesn't work with the updated WinQual site, at least as near as I can tell.

Comment: Time to upgrade? :-)

If you're having any other issues with the new SysDev site it might be worth shooting a mail to sysdev at microsoft dot com - even if the only response is that an MS persion tells you they'll look into it.

Comment: +1. Although the UI of metadata exchange is horrible, it seems to work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of our errors are still showing up under the company hotlist under Reports, but a huge amount are missing.  There is also a link: [Where did my events go?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2011/08/08/the-only-thing-constant-is-change-part-1.aspx), but as far as I can tell this leads to an old article, and does not explain the current changes.

As to contacting Microsoft, you could try the Forums, Sometimes they come back.  I've been told that The [ISV](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isv/threads) is the one to use for WinQual.  There used to be a WinQual specific one but it got rolled up into this one.

Answer (score 0):

The new WER site is indeed difficult to use. E.g., we always requested an edit field per event where we could log the ID of our bug tracking system. They never added this feature but now they removed also their own event ID so we cannot match and track WER reports with our own change management system.

For MEME there seems to be no help or documentation available, doing a WebSearch shows Gareth's blog as one of the top results...

While the WER site looks more fancy but in fact is less usable the MEME tool could turn out to be an improvement.

I know I am not providing many answers here but I wanted to encourage everybody to send complaints and change requests to Microsoft so eventually they might find motiviation to improve things.

You can use the email address provided above, but they pointed me to wer at microsoft dot com

Good luck.