# Mapping product data for Windows Error Reporting

Tags: windows-error-reporting

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336824/winqual-has-moved-to-sysdev-microsoft-com), WinQual has moved and mapping product data for Windows Error Reporting has to be done using Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange (MEME).

Within our automated build process, a script created the XML file for Winqual and automatically did the upload.
Now MEME offers a set of powershell cmdlets to create a mapping file from the product binaries.

By now, I could not find any Documentation for this cmdlets but [this article](http://www.gazoakley.com/content/getting-started-microsoft-ecosystem-metadata-exchange). The powershell script described there unfortunately seems not to set the company name correctly.

Can anyone provide a better documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft says, that there is a known bug in the EMX GUI, displaying the product name instead of the company name in the files listing. Bug will be fixed through EMX upgrades.

Microsoft now also provides an update of the FAQ on [how to use the PowerShell Cmdlets of EMX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2012/03/28/windows-hardware-dashboard-reports-faq.aspx).